How to create a BAYER10 image using OpenCV
I'm having a hard time creating a BAYER10 img using OpenCV, as it does not have any conversion mechanism from RGB8 to BAYER10. I believe OpenCV also doesn't natively support 10 bit pixel, so it's harder.
I was thinking of trying to generate a 16 bit image, and then scaling it down to 10 bit, this might be a solution.
I tried something like this but it doesn't work :
 cv::Mat rgb_image(data->height, data->width, CV_16UC3);

  for (int y = 0; y < data->height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < data->width; x++) {
      rgb_image.at<cv::Vec3w>(y, x)[0] =
          (x + data->frame_counter) % 1024; // Red channel
      rgb_image.at<cv::Vec3w>(y, x)[1] =
          (y + data->frame_counter) % 1024; // Green channel
      rgb_image.at<cv::Vec3w>(y, x)[2] =
          ((x + y + data->frame_counter) / 2) % 1024; // Blue channel
    }
  }


Actually it looks like it's supported by OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html ;

If you want to implement raw BAYER10 --> standard RGB 8-bit conversion, you need to understand: raw Bayer pixel formats, how the color filter is applied, and then about Demosaicing or "Debayering".

@pptaszni Wrong direction, Bayer mosaic can only be an input, not output.

What's the purpose of the % 1024? That won't scale anything, if values exceed 1024 it will just make a mess. | What does "it doesn't work" actually mean? Provide a sample input and a proper [mcve], show us the result and explain why it's not what you expect.

@DanMašek yes yes, that's understood; I see now that OP is actually asking about opposite problem: how to simulate Bayer10 digital camera output, from standard RGB pixels; So, kind of "Bayering" :)

Yep, and that's really not something commonly seen at all in software (some time ago I was playing with predictive compression of Bayer mask images, and spent a good amount of time searching). I mean, generating a naive approximation is trivial (just got to pick the right channels), but it's just... naive. IMHO you'd need a reverse of some more sophisticated Debayering algorithm, taking wider context into account to minimize the quality loss.

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/rgb8-to-bayer10/19098

I don't see the problem. just do what the color filter does: discard information. if you want it to look convincing, apply a "leaky" color mixing matrix to each plane/pitch.
